# How to get all selected child rows in DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I currently quiet new in DataTable jquery .So I faced a big issue right now .I have a table that using a DataTable jquery to create a child rows.That data are get from database.
Every rows in table have a checkbox and will be submit all the selected child rows. My problem is when I want to submit the data ,it seems my code not working as I want if I changing the paginator.Thats meant ,when I select all rows in page 1 and page 2 ,there are only rows in page 2 are submitted .Please anybody help me .Below is my code for your reference. Any help will be appreciate.

All rows that are checked will be submited by click on button

```
$('#OthersSubmit2').on('click', function(e){

      var type_of_invoice = $('#TypeInvoiceId2').val();
      var program_id = $('#ProgramId2').val();
      var sponsorship_id = $('#SponsorshipId2').val();
      var result = [];

      var data_filter = [];
      data_filter = {'type_of_invoice': type_of_invoice,
                     'program_id':program_id,
                     'sponsorship_id':sponsorship_id};


      var rowcollection =  table.$("input:checked", {"page": "all"});
      $.each($(rowcollection), function(index,rows) {
      var data = $(this).parents('tr:eq(0)');

          var transaction = [];
          var data2 = [];
          var stu_master_id = $(data).find('td:eq(0)').attr('id');
          var a = $(data).parent().find('table[id='+stu_master_id+']');
          console.log(a);
          var sub_tbl = $(a).DataTable().$("input:checked", {"page": "all"});
          $.each($(sub_tbl), function(index2,rows2) {

              data2 = $(this).parents('tr:eq(0)');
              var d = $(data2).find('td:eq(0)').attr('id');
              transaction.push(d);
          });
          result.push({'stu_master_id':stu_master_id,
                               'transaction_id':transaction});
      });
      data_filter['data'] = result;
});
```

Comment: `table.$("input:checked", {"page": "all"});` here you are getting all checked rows data?

Comment: And which datatable version are you using? 1.9 or 1.10?

Comment: @mmushtaq DataTables 1.10.7

Comment: @mmushtaq do you know how can I get every rows by table.row(':eq(0)').child() ?